# Non-greedy nginx location regex returning a 404 error

Tags: regex, nginx, pcre

I would like to configure an nginx [`location` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) which will redirect the following URL:

```
/api/v2/<map_id>/region
```

To:

```
http://SOME-URL/api/v2/<map_id>/region
```

Where `map_id` is any string that does not contain `/`.

I have tried:

```
location /api/v2/((?U).*)/region {
    proxy_pass http://SOME-URL/api/v2/$1/region;
}
```

But I still get an 404 error. I've also tried replacing `$1` with `$2`, with no luck.

Any ideas how to fix this regex?

**Update - fixed the region/regions discrepancy.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single `~` was the source of all the pain:

> [In order to use regular expressions, you must always use a prefix:](http://www.nginxtips.com/nginx-location-directive/)
>
> "~"  must be used for case sensitive matching
>
> "~*" must be used for case insensitive matching

So:

```
location ~ /api/v2/([^/]*)/region {
    proxy_pass http://SOME-URL/api/v2/$1/region;
}
```

Did the trick - the `?U` part wasn't even necessary.

The error log at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` gave a useful clue:

```
2014/12/21 12:54:59 [emerg] 7506#0: invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/super_secret_filename_dont_share_on_so.conf:42
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you've got a discrepancy between `region` and `regions`. That'll do it for sure.

Second, you could use a negating character class like this:

```
/api/v2/([^/]*)/region
```

You probably need to escape some slashes in there too, though I'm not entirely sure what Nginx requires.

In any PCRE regex, you'd need to do:

```
\/api\/v2\/([^\/]*)\/region
```

Here it is working on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/mT3xB9/1

Comment: How do I set the regex to be non-greedy?

Comment: Using a `?` after the `*` like this: `\/api\/v2\/([^\/]*?)\/region`. However, since you know specifically what character you don't want, it won't really have any effect on the match.

Comment: Nope, `/api/v2/([^/]*)/region` does not catch `/api/v2/x/region`.

Comment: It does on regex101 if you escape the back slashes `\/`. I don't have an Nginx environment to play around on, but most other regex engines require escaped blackslashes.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, @remus! It seems that my problem did not originate from PCRE syntax, but form NGinx idiosyncrasies - see my answer.